# D3 error when using with react and react-router

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So I am using this react-bubble-chart [component](https://github.com/kauffecup/react-bubble-chart) in my application. It is on the home/main route. On initial page load it works fine. However, if one navigates away and then back again (react-router) it will not load and throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error
    at extendBasis (enclose.js:41)
    at ./node_modules/d3-hierarchy/src/pack/enclose.js.__webpack_exports__.a (enclose.js:9)
    at packEnclose (siblings.js:104)
    at index.js:63
    at Node../node_modules/d3-hierarchy/src/hierarchy/eachAfter.js.__webpack_exports__.a [as eachAfter] (eachAfter.js:10)
    at ReactBubbleChartD3.pack [as bubble] (index.js:24)
    at ReactBubbleChartD3.update (bubble-chart-d3.js:255)
    at new ReactBubbleChartD3 (bubble-chart-d3.js:85)
    at BubbleChart.componentDidMount (index.jsx:163)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:11505)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:12294)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1299)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1338)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1195)
    at commitAllWork (react-dom.development.js:12415)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:12687)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1299)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1338)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1195)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:12800)
    at scheduleUpdateImpl (react-dom.development.js:13185)
    at scheduleUpdate (react-dom.development.js:13124)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:9646)
    at Router../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.ReactComponent.setState (react.development.js:218)
    at Router.js:70
    at listener (createTransitionManager.js:54)
    at createTransitionManager.js:73
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.notifyListeners (createTransitionManager.js:72)
    at setState (createBrowserHistory.js:95)
    at createBrowserHistory.js:120
    at Object.confirmTransitionTo (createTransitionManager.js:44)
    at handlePop (createBrowserHistory.js:118)
    at handlePopState (createBrowserHistory.js:102)
```

As you can see something is causing d3-hierarchy to error. As far as I can see everything is the same as when it runs on page load as in it is getting the same data.

The `react-bubble-chart` module has two parts - the react component and a es6 class that deals with all the D3 code. The react component runs `this.bubbleChart = new ReactBubbleChartD3()` on `componentDidMount` and does run a destroy method of the bubblechart class on componentWillUnmount `this.bubbleChart.destroy()` but this method is empty in the code. Is it likely to be this that is causing the issue?

I have tried adding code to remove the html in the bubblechart container in that destroy method but it makes no difference.

Any ideas?

I have added the files here - https://gist.github.com/garytokyo/64982a5210c3a269f341d8934bb9a1ff

In `bubble-chart-d3.js` it is the following code that causes the error (line 254 or there abouts):

```
const circles = this.svg
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(this.bubble(nodes).descendants(), d => 'g' + d.data._id);
```

To be more specific it is `this.bubble(nodes)`

Comment: Can you paste your react component code?

Comment: Hi I have added the code to a gist - https://gist.github.com/garytokyo/64982a5210c3a269f341d8934bb9a1ff - was way too much to paste in there